# Change css on Multi language website

Tags: angular, right-to-left, ngx-translate, left-to-right

I made a double language website using angular 4 and `ngx-translate`. one `rtl` and the other one `ltr`. How can I change the direction of text and text alignment on language change?

I cant use because I don't know how to change this attribute in angular.

```
html:lang(en) h1{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Any way I can target each language in `style.css`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to modify in order to convert a left-to-right stylesheet to a right-to-left one:

- Change `html` tag so it becomes `<html dir="rtl">`. This sets the base direction for the **whole document** to be right-to-left.
- Modify `margin` values when `margin-left` and `margin-right` of some element are **not equal**. The same applies for `padding`.
- Change the values of **position properties**: `left` and `right`. For example: `left: 200px` on some element in a `ltr` document becomes `right: 200px` in a `rtl` document.

After that, take a look at the page, and see if you need any additional minor modifications like `box-shadow`, `text-shadow`, etc.

#### CSSJanus

You can use [CSSJanus](https://cssjanus.github.io/) to do the second and third steps above for you. However, you will need to do the `<html>` step yourself.

#### For more information

Visit [this page](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir) from W3C, which answers the question:

> How should I use the dir attribute and related markup to set text direction on structural elements in HTML?

Answer (score 2):

If you have different css file for each language. try this.

```
changeLanguage() {
if(use your condition here){
  document.documentElement.lang = 'ar';
  document.documentElement.dir = 'rtl';
  sessionStorage.setItem('lang','ar');
  let tag = document.getElementById("mainCss");//add id to link tag of your css file
  tag.setAttribute('href', "assets/css/styleAr.css");
}else{
  document.documentElement.lang = 'en';
  document.documentElement.dir = 'ltr';
  sessionStorage.setItem('lang','en');
  let tag = document.getElementById("mainCss");
  tag.setAttribute('href', "assets/css/style.css");
}


}
```